# Embedded Elastic with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I have used embedded elastic as part of a Spring application in Java like this:

```
Node node;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Bean
public Client es() {
    node = nodeBuilder().local(true).node();
    Client client = node.client();
    boolean indexExists = client.admin().indices().prepareExists(INDEX).execute().actionGet().isExists();
    if (!indexExists) {
        client.admin().indices().prepareCreate(INDEX).execute().actionGet();
    }
    return client;
}
```

I'm trying to do something similar with NodeJS so I don't have to create an elastic search instance separately(super low traffic).  In the Spring case, I just set .local(true) and it's good to go.  I can't find any option like that in Node.

This is what I'm doing now

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
//    log: 'trace',
    host: 'localhost:9200'
});
```

and it works fine for an external server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have Elasticsearch Node Client in NodeJS. The second method is the way to go.